# fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'sso'

Tags: git, macos, terminal, single-sign-on

I try to run this command

```
❯ git clone sso://my-internal/inli                                                                               [17:10:31]
Cloning into 'inli'...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'sso'
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that Git doesn't know how to handle the sso protocol. See: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers for more understanding.

There's very little on the interwebs about Git and Single Sign On, so I suspect you're out in the tall grass with the lions and tigers here, but I suggest:

1. Try the HTTPS interface. You might get lucky and the SSO just works. And I could win the lottery tonight, but hey.
2. Talk to the org that owns the git server. They may be able to provide you more assistance. Often it's larger organizations that use SSO (they're the only ones with the money to hire the people to beat that stuff into shape) and they may have a solution for you.
3. Contact the vendor of your SSO "solution" and see what they suggest.